# Verb form of statistics

Tags: single-word-requests, word-usage

May I ask what is the verb form of statistics or is there any replacement word with the meaning of "the act of doing statistics"?

Comment: English doesn't really have a single word for the act of doing everything. Is there a particular part of stats you're trying to capture? (Eg. "Regressing")

Comment: I just want to say "do statistics" in other way

Comment: Do you have a context, then? It would really help.

Comment: What is the verb corresponding to 'biology'? 'Biologizing'?

Comment: I would use "analyze" if you think you've overused the phrase "do statistics on", and it's clear from context that you mean "analyze statistically".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The term *statistics* refers to the numbers that are generated by statistical analysis. Perhaps the phrase *analyze statistically* would meet your needs.

Various specific activities that result in the output of certain statistics have single word verb forms, such as *average*, *correlate*, *sum*, *equate*, and *tally*.

Answer (score 4):

Well, Google reports some 300 instances of "statisticked" on the web.  And the OED has *statisticize*, v. To arrange in the form of statistics... to collect or employ statistics....

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps not a perfect match but the word, "figure", as in "figure up the tally" or "Figures never lie, but liars figure".